# windows authentification and user and password SSO

Tags: .net-core, ldap, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

How to allow both windows authentication and user and password authentication in IdentityServer4? Also, how do I use Active Directory as authentication provider?

Comment: looks like a straightforward process of using `AddIdentity` and `AddMicrosoftAccount`. Can you show what you have tired and where you are stuck?

Comment: Check out http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html. This uses google as an example of external authentication but switching that out for ADFS or Azure Active Directory should be pretty straightforward.